# How to call the value that contains a column using the value of a field from another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to move the value of each year from `df_2` to `df_1`.

```
countries <- c("USA","Canada","Denmark","Albania", "Turkey","France", "Italy")
values <- c(100, 1000, 300, 300,7000, 8343,9211)
year <- c(2007,2008,2009,2008,2008,2009,2008)
df_1 <- data.frame(countries, values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

countries <- c("USA","Canada","Denmark","Albania", "Turkey","France", "Italy")
`2007` <- c(2,3,5,6,7,8,8)
`2008` <- c(23,23,65,86,97,98,68)
`2009` <- c(12,33,35,46,67,78,88)

df_2 <- data.frame(countries, `2007`, `2008`, `2009`, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Mi idea about how to solve this:

```
df_1 <- dplyr::mutate(df_1, ifelse((df_1$country == df_2$country), df_2$(df_1$year), 0)
```

The expected result is this a new column contain the values from each year and country:

```
df_1$value_that_year <- c(2,23,35,86,97,78,68)
```

Comment: How do you know which values from which year to select? `df_2` contains values for three years, but `value_that_year` only reports one value. What is `"that_year"`?

Comment: Because I take `df_1$countries[1]` and `df_1$year[1]` (USA, 2007), and with those values, I am going to the second dataframe `df_2` And I took the value "2".

Comment: *"And I took the value "2""* Not clear. *Why* did you take the value `2`? If you want to join/match entries from two `data.frame`s you need a common variable by which you join/match. I assume that variable is `year`. So `df_1` would need a column with values for `year` according to which you select entries from `df_2`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I assume you forgot to include a `year` column in `df_1`, which unfortunately makes your example not reproducible.**

Let's add a `year` column to `df_1`, according to which we select entries from `df_2`.

```
countries <- c("USA","Canada","Denmark","Albania", "Turkey","France", "Italy")
values <- c(100, 1000, 300, 300,7000, 8343,9211)
year <- c(2007,2008,2009,2008,2008,2009,2008)
df_1 <- data.frame(countries, values, year, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then this becomes a simple matter of spreading `df_2` from wide to long, and then using a `right_join` to join both `data.frame`s on `year`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_2 %>%
    gather(year, value_that_year, -countries) %>%
    mutate(year = as.numeric(sub("X", "", year))) %>%
    right_join(df_1)
#  countries year value_that_year values
#1       USA 2007               2    100
#2    Canada 2008              23   1000
#3   Denmark 2009              35    300
#4   Albania 2008              86    300
#5    Turkey 2008              97   7000
#6    France 2009              78   8343
#7     Italy 2008              68   9211
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am checking the library `tidyr` in order to understand how to use `gather`. And also I am completing the example.